# Find a ControlTemplate from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a xaml file with this code:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="lvCol3"
                Header="Quantità"
                Width="120">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Control x:Name="host">
                <Control.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Entity.Quantita}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Control.Template>
            </Control>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="host" Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Name="myControlTemplate" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I would manage `myControlTemplate` from code behind in order to assign different UI object.

I try to use `FindResource` but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to extract your ControlTemplate to a resource: then you can use FindResource.

Something like this:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
         <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Path=Entity.Quantita}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  ...

  <GridViewColumn 
     x:Name="lvCol3"
     Header="Quantità"
     Width="120">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Control x:Name="host" Template="{StaticResouce MyControlTemplate}">   
               </Control>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn>

  ...
</UserControl>
```

Then in the code for your UserControl (or whatever is the root element) you can do

```
var resource = FindResource("MyControlTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
```